# Find a basis for a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have to find a basis for the vectors satisfying $x_1=2x_4$

I interpreted this as $S=\Bigg\{
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^4 \Bigg|
x_1 =2x_4 \Bigg\}$

I have proved that this is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, and now want to find the basis.

Since $\vec{x}$ has 4 unknowns with one equation, I believe there should be three free variables.

Let $x_4=t, x_3 = s, x_2 = r$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2t\\s\\r\\t
\end{bmatrix}=
t
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\0\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}
+ s
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
+r
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is this a basis for the vectors satisfying $x_1=2x_4$?

Comment: This looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Since the generating set
\begin{align*}
S = \{(2,0,0,1), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0)\}
\end{align*}

is linear independent (why?), you just have found a basis.